# Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

When I check our SMTP configuration with this tool:

http://mxtoolbox.com

We get the following error:

```
The hostname was not found in the reverse dns lookup. In other words, the PTR for
your server IP address (reverse lookup) does not match the DNS name (forward lookup).
```

even if they are both `mail.domain.ext`

What else should I check?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you check anything else? Are you concerned about other possible problems? Why not fix this one first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that both are mail.domain.ext, did you just now fix those records? Remember that DNS answers get cached. Try doing a reverse lookup from somewhere else on the internet.

It may take you anywhere from an hour to a day for the cached data to expire from mxtoolbox.com's DNS servers.

Comment: 24h are already passed and from a missing reverse DNS now I have one. Can the remote.domain.ext, that Windows SBS2011 suggest to create, interfere with this?

Comment: Let's say your mail.domain.ext was at 192.0.2.66. You have an A record for mail.domain.ext. for it. You also need a 66.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa PTR mail.domain.ext. record. Worse, you have to make sure that external DNS servers know to reach your DNS server to do that reverse lookup. Can you confirm when you use http://remote.12dt.com/ that the server's IP resolves correctly? Can you tell me the real domain.ext?

Comment: If I ping mail.domain.ext I get the external static IP from assigned ISP. If I ping remote.domain.ext I get the internal static IP of the machine.

Comment: I'm worried that you're pinging from your own network and also using your own, local DNS server. But is your internal server also your external DNS server? As I asked before, when you go to remote.12dt.com and type in your mail server's IP, does it give you the answer mail.domain.ext? Sorry if I'm being obnoxious.

Comment: Yes it returns mail.domain.ext and now that additional 24h are passed even the http://mxtoolbox.com give a positive feedback.